# Time value based continuous request on android

Tags: java, android, request, android-volley

I'm trying to continuously send a request. I get the time variables from my request. I wanted to send the request again and again by checking the values I get from the request. Here is my request:

```
 public JSONHandler() {
        request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            channelObject = response.getJSONObject("channel0");
                            song = channelObject.getString("song");
                            artist = channelObject.getString("artist");
                            duration = channelObject.getInt("duration");
                            playedAt = channelObject.getInt("playedat");
                            channelImg = channelObject.getString("image_extralarge");
//                            channel0 = new Channel(song, artist, duration, playedAt, channelImg);


                            channelObject = response.getJSONObject("channel1");
                            song = channelObject.getString("song");
                            artist = channelObject.getString("artist");
                            duration = channelObject.getInt("duration");
                            playedAt = channelObject.getInt("playedat");
                            channelImg = channelObject.getString("image_extralarge");
//                            channel1 = new Channel(song, artist, duration, playedAt, channelImg);

                            channelObject = response.getJSONObject("channel2");
                            song = channelObject.getString("song");
                            artist = channelObject.getString("artist");
                            duration = channelObject.getInt("duration");
                            playedAt = channelObject.getInt("playedat");
                            channelImg = channelObject.getString("image_extralarge");
//                            channel2 = new Channel(song, artist, duration, playedAt, channelImg);

                            channelObject = response.getJSONObject("channel3");
                            song = channelObject.getString("song");
                            artist = channelObject.getString("artist");
                            duration = channelObject.getInt("duration");
                            playedAt = channelObject.getInt("playedat");
                            channelImg = channelObject.getString("image_extralarge");
//                            channel3 = new Channel(song, artist, duration, playedAt, channelImg);

                            channelObject = response.getJSONObject("channel4");
                            song = channelObject.getString("song");
                            artist = channelObject.getString("artist");
                            duration = channelObject.getInt("duration");
                            playedAt = channelObject.getInt("playedat");
                            channelImg = channelObject.getString("image_extralarge");
//                            channel4 = new Channel(song, artist, duration, playedAt, channelImg);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

I should check the "playedAt" + "duration" and after that I wanted to send a request again. I implement this request in my MainActivity like this:

```
JSONHandler jsonHandler = new JSONHandler();
```

After checking the time I wanted to send the request again so I update the values I need. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Insert your code to a function instead of the constructor, and every time you want to create a request, call to this function

Comment: The time I want is in the request. How can I get it then?

Comment: First, move the code into another function. After you did it, you can check the duration you want and call the function you created after this duration using `new Timer().schedule(A_RUNNABLE_WHICH_CALL_YOUR_FUNCTION, duration)`